# Cannot get Triangle to Display with OpenGL in GLFW

Tags: c++, opengl, shader, glfw

I have been following the Modern Opengl Tutorials on YouTube by Nico Cvitak to help me transition from SDL to OpenGl/GLFW; here is a link to the lesson I can't get to work: [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2K_R4C1UP-c][1]

Here is my code:

*myVertexShader.vs*

```html
#version 150 core

in vec2 v_pos;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(v_pos, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

*myFragmentShader.fs*

```html
#version 150 core

out vec4 fragData;

void main()
{
    fragData = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
}
```

*main.cpp*

```html
#define GLFW_INCLUDE_GLCOREARB

#include <iostream>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <OpenGL/OpenGL.h>
#include "ShaderUtils.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    GLFWwindow * window;
    
    //Initialize the library
    if (!glfwInit())
        return -1;
    
    //Specify Hints
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 2);
    
    //Create a windowed mode window and its OpenGL context
    window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Mojicon", NULL, NULL);
    if (!window)
    {
        glfwTerminate();
        return 1;
    }
    
    //Make the window's context current
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    std::cout << glGetString(GL_VERSION) << std::endl;
    
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    
    GLuint vertexShader = ShaderUtils::createShaderFromFile("myVertexShader.vs", GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    GLuint fragmentShader = ShaderUtils::createShaderFromFile("myFragmentShader.fs", GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    
    GLuint shaderProgram = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
    
    glBindFragDataLocation(shaderProgram, 0, "fragData");
    
    glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);
    GLint linkStatus;
    glGetProgramiv(shaderProgram, GL_LINK_STATUS, &linkStatus);
    if (linkStatus != GL_TRUE)
    {
        cout << "Program Link Failed!" << endl;
        GLint infoLogLength;
        glGetProgramiv(shaderProgram, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &infoLogLength);
        GLchar * infoLog = new GLchar[infoLogLength + 1];
        glGetShaderInfoLog(shaderProgram, infoLogLength + 1, NULL, infoLog);
        cout << infoLog << endl;
        delete infoLog;
        
        return 0;
    }
    
    glUseProgram(shaderProgram);
    
    //vertex buffer objects
    GLuint myVBO;
    glGenBuffers(1, &myVBO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, myVBO);
    
    GLfloat bufferData[] =
    {
        +0.0, +0.5,
        -0.5, -0.5,
        +0.5, -0.5,
    };
    
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(bufferData), bufferData, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, NULL);
    
    GLuint myVAO;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &myVAO);
    glBindVertexArray(myVAO);
    
    GLint positionLoc = glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "v_pos");
    
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(positionLoc);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, myVBO);
    glVertexAttribPointer(positionLoc, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 2 * sizeof(GLfloat), 0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, NULL);
    glBindVertexArray(NULL);
    
    //Loop the window until closed
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        //Render here
        GLint windowWidth, windowHeight;
        glfwGetWindowSize(window, &windowWidth, &windowHeight);
        glViewport(0, 0, windowWidth, windowHeight);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        
        glBindVertexArray(myVAO);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
        glBindVertexArray(NULL);
        
        //Poll for events
        glfwPollEvents();
        
        //Swap buffers
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    }
    
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &myVBO);
    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &myVAO);
    glDeleteShader(vertexShader);
    glDeleteShader(fragmentShader);
    glDeleteProgram(shaderProgram);
    glfwDestroyWindow(window);
    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

*ShaderUtil.h*

```html
#define GLFW_INCLUDE_GLCOREARB

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <streambuf>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

using namespace std;

class ShaderUtils
{
public:
    static GLuint createShaderFromFile(const GLchar * path, GLenum shaderType);
};
```

*ShaderUtil.cpp*

```html
#include "ShaderUtils.h"

GLuint ShaderUtils::createShaderFromFile(const GLchar * path, GLenum shaderType)
{
    GLuint shaderID = glCreateShader(shaderType);
    
    ifstream fin;
    fin.open(path);
    if (!fin.is_open())
    {
        cout << "File Not Found '" << path << "'!" << endl;
        return -1;
    }
    string source((istreambuf_iterator<GLchar>(fin)), istreambuf_iterator<GLchar>());
    fin.close();
    
    const GLchar * shaderSource = source.c_str();
    glShaderSource(shaderID, 1, &shaderSource, NULL);
    
    glCompileShader(shaderID);
    
    GLint compileStatus;
    glGetShaderiv(shaderID, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &compileStatus);
    
    if (compileStatus != GL_TRUE)
    {
        cout << "Shader Failed To Compile: '" << path << "'!" << endl;
        GLint infoLogLength;
        glGetShaderiv(shaderID, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &infoLogLength);
        GLchar * infoLog = new GLchar[infoLogLength + 1];
        glGetShaderInfoLog(shaderID, infoLogLength + 1, NULL, infoLog);
        cout << infoLog << endl;
        delete infoLog;
        
        return -1;
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

I tried to make this code nearly identical with the tutorials code, and I cannot for the life of me find any differences.  Help me find the problem (there are no bugs) and explain it to me.

Comment: Can you explain what exactly "cannot get it to work" means? Does it compile? Does it crash? Do you get an empty screen? Do you get any errors?

Comment: I can't see you moving the "camera" (as is - transforming the world coordinates before rendering). So the question is simple - are you sure you're in a position to actually see the triangle?

Comment: @derhass It opens a black window (or more accurately whatever color I put into "glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)").  The triangle won't show up though; which is where I am having a problem.  It compiles, doesn't crash, and doesn't return any errors. :)

Comment: @PawełStawarz: The code is directly drawing in clip space, and the triangle in the range [-0.5,0.5] should actually be visible with that vertex shader.

Comment: @DamianAnderson: The only thing I can see are these `glBind*(...,NULL)` things. GL object names are always `GLuint`s, while `NULL` is a pointer, you should use `0` for these. However, that would not explain the behavior you get. I may be missing something, but that code should indeed draw a white triangle, quite centered in your window. At least on OSX, where you don't need to use the extension mechanism. But that isn't the issue here, too, as your code simply wouldn't compile and especially link on other platforms. You could still add a `glGetError()` and check if really no error is reported.

Comment: @darhass Then it might be a problem with how I have Xcode set up.  I'll try creating a new project and see if it works there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `createShaderFromFile()` method always returns 0:

```
GLuint ShaderUtils::createShaderFromFile(const GLchar * path, GLenum shaderType)
{
    ...
    return 0;
}
```

You use this return value as a shader id:

```
GLuint vertexShader = ShaderUtils::createShaderFromFile(
        "myVertexShader.vs", GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
GLuint fragmentShader = ShaderUtils::createShaderFromFile(
        "myFragmentShader.fs", GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
```

These values will come out as 0. To make this work, you will need to return the shader id from the method:

```
GLuint ShaderUtils::createShaderFromFile(const GLchar * path, GLenum shaderType)
{
    ...
    return shaderID;
}
```

You should be able to track down this kind of problem by stepping through the code in a debugger.